# Ancient character sequence

Tags: knowledge, letter-sequence

What is the next character in this ancient sequence: a, a, a, a, n, a, a, a, a, a, a, ?

What is your reasoning?

Comment: I normally don't like sequence puzzles, but this one was neat! There's a very clear "hook" that could lead you to the answer, and the answer is immediately self-confirming once you have it. Good puzzle!

Comment: Thank you @Deusovi! That means a lot to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The next letter in this sequence is:

> **u**

As these are:

> The last letters in the names of characters making up the [**Greek alphabet**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet), which has been in use since *ancient* times:
>
>  Alph**a**, Bet**a**, Gamm**a**, Delt**a**, Epsilo**n**, Zet**a**, Et**a**, Thet**a**, Iot**a**, Kapp**a**, Lambd**a**...
>
>  And the next character in the Greek alphabet is M**u**.

Comment: Well done you got it!